# Python retrieve columns value from SQL

Tags: python, sql

I have a cursor in python which retrieve a row from a database:

```
crx5 = con.cursor()
crx5.execute('select colA, colB, colC from nr')
crx5.fetchall()
```

There is only 1 row and I don't know how to retrieve the column values in some variables like:

```
var1=colA value
var2=colB value
var3=colC value
```

Pleas help me!

Thanks

Comment: You haven't used `fetchall()` and that isn't valid python syntax. Please follow some tutorials e.g. [this](https://pythonspot.com/tag/sql/) before asking. Though they use SQLite, the concepts are comparable.

Comment: yes, i've missed fetchall().

Answer (score 1):

Just assign each column in fetchall() to a variable:

```
crx5 = conn.cursor()
crx5.execute(f"select colA, colB, colC from nr ;")
        for colA, colB, colC in crx5.fetchall():
            print(colC, colB, colA) # column swapping as an example
```

If you want a list of each column, then just append each row's column to an empty list, e.g:

```
col1 = [] 
for cola, colb, colc in crx5.fetchall():
    col1.append(cola)
```